# inserting ordered characters in trie

Tags: java, data-structures, tree, nodes

i am writing an insert method in trie tree but i want to keep order between characters but there is some wrong that i couldn't know because the root of the tree still null

```
public void insert (String name,TrieNode r)
{
    if(r==null && name.length()>0)
    {
        r=new TrieNode(name.charAt(0));
        if(name.length()>1)
         insert(name.substring(1),r.getFirstChild());
    }
    else if(r.getletter()==name.charAt(0))
    {
        name=removeFirstChar(name);
        insert(name,r.getFirstChild());
    }
    else
    {
        if(name.charAt(0) < r.getletter())
        {
            TrieNode n=new TrieNode(name.charAt(0));
            n.setNextSibling(r);
            r.setFirstChild(n);
        }
        else
            insert(name,r.getNextSibling());

    }
}
```

Comment: it would help if you format your code.

Comment: i am sorry but this is first time for me to ask it is good now

Comment: Maybe you can include the code for TrieNode & show us an example of how the tree is supposed to look like? i.e., the order between characters that you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert in Java, but just from reading the first couple lines of your code, I noticed that you are initializing `r=new TrieNode(name.charAt(0));`. This doesn't work in Java because the objects are passed by value not by reference, so you basically can't change what they are pointing to inside the function.

Read [this](http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm) article for more details.